# How to AUTO Open .doc files in Ubuntu FROM WEB

Tags: firefox, libreoffice, doc

I am trying to open Microsoft.doc files from the Web however I am unable to do this. Here is a scenario of what I am currently experiencing.

I go to website where I see `.doc` file; 
I click on `File`; 
Browser asks me how I want to open document (with `Amarok` as default device);
I click drop-down and scroll to `libreoffice-writer.desktop`;
I click `OK`; 
File downloads in `temp` folder yet nothing happens.

Do you guys have any idea why this isn't working?

NOTE: I am still able to open the file by first downloading it and opening it from within Libre-office-writer. However I am trying to bypass the extra steps by opening straight from web-broswer.

Also, I am using latest version of Firefox

---

Here is what I see when I open file in G-edit:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
#
# This file is part of the LibreOffice project.
#
# This Source Code Form is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public
# License, v. 2.0. If a copy of the MPL was not distributed with this
# file, You can obtain one at http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/.
#
# This file incorporates work covered by the following license notice:
#
#   Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
#   contributor license agreements. See the NOTICE file distributed
#   with this work for additional information regarding copyright
#   ownership. The ASF licenses this file to you under the Apache
#   License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file
#   except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of
#   the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 .
#
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Terminal=false
Icon=libreoffice-writer
Type=Application
Categories=Office;WordProcessor;X-Red-Hat-Base;X-MandrivaLinux-Office-Wordprocessors;
Exec=libreoffice --writer %U
MimeType=application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text;application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-template;application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-web;application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-master;application/vnd.sun.xml.writer;application/vnd.sun.xml.writer.template;application/vnd.sun.xml.writer.global;application/msword;application/vnd.ms-word;application/x-doc;application/x-hwp;application/rtf;text/rtf;application/vnd.wordperfect;application/wordperfect;application/vnd.lotus-wordpro;application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroenabled.12;application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template;application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroenabled.12;application/vnd.ms-works;application/vnd.stardivision.writer-global;application/x-extension-txt;application/x-t602;text/plain;application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-flat-xml;application/x-fictionbook+xml;application/macwriteii;application/x-aportisdoc;application/prs.plucker;application/vnd.palm;application/clarisworks;
Name=LibreOffice Writer
GenericName=Word Processor
GenericName[nb]=Skriveprogram
GenericName[xh]=Word Processor
GenericName[or]=ଶବ୍ଦ ସଞ୍ଚାଳକ
GenericName[cy]=Prosesydd Geiriau
GenericName[tr]=Kelime İşlemci
GenericName[it]=Elaboratore di testo
GenericName[nl]=Tekstverwerker
GenericName[sl]=Urejevalnik besedila
GenericName[nso]=Sebopi sa mantšu
GenericName[sr]=Уређивач текста
GenericName[ko]=워드 프로세서
GenericName[eu]=Testu prozesatzailea
GenericName[kmr_Latn]=Kiryarê Peyvan
GenericName[rw]=Musesenguramagambo
GenericName[pa_IN]=ਵਰਡ ਪਰੋਸੈਸਰ
GenericName[zh_CN]=字处理器
GenericName[en_ZA]=Word Processor
GenericName[ar]=معالج المستندات
GenericName[ml]=വേര്‍ഡ് പ്രൊസസ്സര്‍
GenericName[uk]=Текстовий процесор
GenericName[ja]=ワードプロセッサ
GenericName[en_GB]=Word Processor
GenericName[hu]=Szövegszerkesztő
GenericName[sk]=Textový procesor
GenericName[br]=Kewerier testenn
GenericName[as]=Word প্ৰচেছৰ
GenericName[mk]=Обработка на текст
GenericName[vi]=Xử lý từ
GenericName[ne]=वर्ड प्रोसेसर
GenericName[zh_TW]=文書處理器
GenericName[pt]=Processador de texto
GenericName[ga]=Próiseálaí Focal
GenericName[st]=Word Processor
GenericName[bn]=ওয়ার্ড প্রসেসর
GenericName[fa]=واژه‌پرداز
GenericName[ts]=Word Processor
GenericName[ve]=Word Processor
GenericName[nr]=Word Processor
GenericName[bs]=Program za obradu teksta
GenericName[gd]=Giullachair teacsa
GenericName[es]=Procesador de texto
GenericName[tn]=Word Processor
GenericName[ro]=Procesor de text
GenericName[ta]=சொற்செயலி
GenericName[tg]=Word Processor
GenericName[th]=Word Processor
GenericName[lv]=Tekstapstrādes programma
GenericName[te]=వర్డ్ ప్రాసెసర్
GenericName[id]=Pengolah Kata
GenericName[lt]=Tekstų rengyklė
GenericName[ca_valencia]=Processador de textos
GenericName[si]=ලිපි සකසනය
GenericName[uz]=Matn protsessori
GenericName[af]=Woordverwerker
GenericName[en]=Word Processor
GenericName[de]=Textverarbeitung
GenericName[gu]=વર્ડ પ્રોસેસર
GenericName[da]=Tekstbehandling
GenericName[ug]=يېزىق بىر تەرەپ قىلىش
GenericName[zu]=Word Processor
GenericName[fi]=Tekstinkäsittely
GenericName[be]=Тэкставы працэсар
GenericName[ru]=Текстовый процессор
GenericName[hi]=वर्ड प्रोसेसर
GenericName[dz]=Word Processor
GenericName[km]=កម្មវិធី​វាយ​អត្ថបទ
GenericName[pt_BR]=Editor de texto
GenericName[eo]=Vortprocesilo
GenericName[ca]=Processador de textos
GenericName[ka]=Word Processor
GenericName[om]=Hujeessaa Jecha
GenericName[ss]=Word Processor
GenericName[sv]=Ordbehandlare
GenericName[el]=Επεξεργαστής Word
GenericName[hr]=Program za obradu teksta
GenericName[mn]=Ворд боловсруулагч
GenericName[ast]=Procesador de testos
GenericName[mr]=वर्ड प्रोसेसर
GenericName[pl]=Word Processor
GenericName[gl]=Procesador de textos
GenericName[cs]=Textový procesor
GenericName[et]=Tekstitöötlus
GenericName[nn]=Teksthandsamar
GenericName[bg]=Текстообработка
GenericName[kk]=Мәтіндік процессор
GenericName[is]=Ritvinnsluforrit
GenericName[fr]=Traitement de texte
GenericName[he]=מעבד תמלילים
GenericName[oc]=Tractament de tèxte
Comment=Create and edit text and graphics in letters, reports, documents and Web pages by using Writer.
Comment[ko]=Writer를 사용하여 편지, 보고서, 문서 및 웹 페이지에서 텍스트와 그림을 만들고 편집할 수 있습니다.
Comment[si]=Writer භාවිතා කරමින් ලිපි වල පෙළ සහ චිත්‍රක, වාර්තා, ලිපි සහ වියුණු පිටු සාදන්න සහ වෙනස් කරන්න.
Comment[om]=Bareessaa fayyadamuun xalayaalee, gabasota, galmeewwanii fi fuulota saphaphuu irratti barruu fi saxxatoo uumi, gulaali.
Comment[ar]=إنشاء النصوص والرسومات في الخطابات، والتقارير، والمستندات وصفحات ويب وتحريرها باستخدام رايتر.
Comment[id]=Mengolah teks dan gambar pada surat, laporan, dokumen, dan halaman Web menggunakan Writer.
Comment[kmr_Latn]=Nivîs û grafîkên di name, rapor, belge û rûpelên torê de bî Writerê çêbike û sererast bike.
Comment[et]=Writer võimaldab luua ja redigeerida kirjade, aruannete, dokumentide ning veebilehtede teksti ja pilte.
Comment[en]=Create and edit text and graphics in letters, reports, documents and Web pages by using Writer.
Comment[nso]=Hlama le go lokiša sengwalwa le dikrafiki mangwalong, dipegong, ditokumenteng le matlakaleng a wepe ka go diriša Writer.
Comment[or]=ରାଇଟର ଉପୟୋଗ କରି ପତ୍ରଗୁଡିକରେ, ରିପୋର୍ଟରେ,ଦଲିଲଗୁଡିକରେ ଏବଂ ଉଏବ୍ ପୃଷ୍ଠାଗୁଡିକରେ ଟେକ୍ସଟ ଏବଂ ଲେଖାଚିତ୍ରଗୁଡିକୁ ସୃଷ୍ଟି ଏବଂ ସମ୍ପାଦନ କରନ୍ତୁ।
Comment[fi]=Luo ja muokkaa tekstiä ja grafiikkaa kirjeisiin, raportteihin, tekstiasiakirjoihin ja internet-sivuihin Writer-ohjelmalla.
Comment[km]=បង្កើត និង​កែ​សម្រួល​អត្ថបទ និង​ក្រាហ្វិក​ក្នុង​សំបុត្រ របាយការណ៍ ឯកសារ និង​ទំព័រ​បណ្តាញ​ដោយ​ប្រើ Writer ។
Comment[lt]=Tekstų rengykle galima kurti laiškus, ataskaitas, kitus dokumentus ir tinklalapius, įterpti į juos paveikslus.
Comment[bs]=Pravite i mijenjajte tekst i grafiku u pismima, izvještajima, dokumentima i Web stranicama koristeći Writer.
Comment[kk]=Writer көмегімен хаттарда, құжаттарда, есептемелерде және веб-парақтарда мәтінді және суреттерді жасау және түзетуге болады.
Comment[is]=Búa til og breyta texta og myndefni í bréfum, skýrslum, skjölum og vefsíðum með því að nota Writer.
Comment[vi]=Tạo và sửa văn bản và đồ họa trong lá thư, báo cáo, tài liệu và trang Web bằng Writer.
Comment[uk]=Створення та редагування тексту та графіки у листах, звітах, документах та веб-сторінках.
Comment[zh_TW]=使用 Writer 可以在信件、報告、文件和網頁中建立與編輯文字和圖形。
Comment[el]=Δημιουργία και επεξεργασία κειμένου και γραφικών σε επιστολές, αναφορές, έγγραφα και ιστοσελίδες με τη χρήση του Writer.
Comment[af]=Skep en redigeer teks en grafika in briewe, verslae, dokumente en webbladsye met Writer.
Comment[it]=Usando Writer, potete creare e modificare il testo e le immagini di lettere, rapporti, documenti e pagine Web.
Comment[gd]=Cruthaich is deasaich teacsa is dealbhan ann an litrichean, aithisgean, sgrìobhainnean is duilleagan-lìn le Writer.
Comment[sv]=Skapa och redigera text och grafik i brev, rapporter, dokument och webbsidor med hjälp av Writer.
Comment[pl]=Twórz i edytuj listy, raporty, dokumenty i strony www wykorzystując program Writer.
Comment[zu]=Yenza futhi ulungise umbhalo nemidwebo esezinhlamvini zamagama, emibikweni, emafayelini nasemakhasini eWebhu ngokusebenzisa i-Writer.
Comment[ve]=Vhumbani ni dovhe ni lulamise ḽiṅwalwa na dzigirafiki kha maṅwalo, mivhigo, maṅwalo na masiaṱari a Web nga u shumisa Writer.
Comment[cs]=Writer umožňuje vytvářet a upravovat text a grafiku v dopisech, sestavách, dokumentech a webových stránkách.
Comment[hi]=लेखक के प्रयोग से पत्र, रिपोर्ट, दस्तावेज़ में पाठ और आरेख बनाता है और संपादित करता है.
Comment[sr]=Пишите и уређујте текст и графику у писмима, извештајима и веб страницама у Писцу.
Comment[gl]=Crear e editar texto ou imaxes en cartas, informes, documentos e páxinas web usando Writer.
Comment[es]=Cree y edite texto y gráficos en cartas, informes, documentos y páginas Web con Writer.
Comment[bn]=রাইটার ব্যবহার করে চিঠিপত্র, রিপোর্ট, নথি এবং ওয়েবপেজের লেখা ও ছবি তৈরি এবং সম্পাদনা করুন।
Comment[ga]=Cruthaigh téacs agus grafaicí i litreacha, tuairiscí, cáipéisí, agus leathanaigh Ghréasáin le Writer.
Comment[tn]=Create and edit text and graphics in letters, reports, documents and Web pages by using Writer.
Comment[pt]=Criar e editar texto e imagens em cartas, relatórios, documentos e páginas web com o Writer.
Comment[cy]=Creu a golygu testun a graffigau mewn llythyron, adroddiadau, dogfennau a thudalennau Gwe gyda Writer.
Comment[hr]=Stvorite i uredite tekst i grafiku u pisma, izvještajima, dokumentima i internet stranicama koristeći Writer.
Comment[ja]=Writer を使用して、レター、レポート、ドキュメントおよび Web ページのテキストおよび図を作成および編集します。
Comment[he]=יצירה ועריכה של טקסט וגרפיקה במכתבים, דוחות, מסמכים ודפי אינטרנט באמצעות Writer.
Comment[uz]=Writer yordamida hisobotlar, matn hujjatlari, veb sahifalar yaratish va tahrirlash.
Comment[da]=LibreOffice4.2-tekstdokument
Comment[br]=Writer - Krouiñ hag embann testennoù ha skeudennoù evit lizhiri, danevelloù, teulioù ha pajennoù Web.
Comment[bg]=С Writer можете да създавате и редактирате текст и графики в писма, отчети, документи и уебстраници.
Comment[fa]=با استفاده از کاتب، متن و گرافیک نامه‌ها، گزارش‌ها، نوشتارها و صفحات وب را ایجاد یا ویرایش کنید.
Comment[lv]=Veidot un rediģēt tekstu un grafisku vēstulēs, atskaitēs, dokumentos un tīmekļa lapās, lietojot Writer.
Comment[ca]=Creeu i editeu textos i gràfics en cartes, informes, documents i pàgines web amb el Writer.
Comment[hu]=Levelek, jelentések, dokumentumok és weboldalak szövegének és grafikájának létrehozása és szerkesztése a Writer használatával.
Comment[zh_CN]=使用 Writer 创建并编辑信函、报表、文档和网页中的文本和图形。
Comment[th]=สร้างและแก้ไขข้อความและกราฟิกส์ในจดหมาย รายงาน เอกสาร และหน้าเว็บโดยการใช้ Writer
Comment[mk]=Креирајте и уредувајте текст и графика во писма, извештаи, документи и веб-страници со користење на Writer.
Comment[ka]=ქმნის და ასწორებს დოკუმენტებსა და დიაგრამებს წერილებში, მოხსენებებში, დოკუმენტებში და ვებ-გვერდებში Writer-ის მეშვეობით.
Comment[oc]=Writer - Creacion e edicion de tèxtes e d'imatges per corrièrs, rapòrts, documents e paginas Web.
Comment[te]=పత్రము మరియు లేఖ యొక్క చిత్రరూపములు,నివేదనలు,పత్రములు మరియు వ్రాయు యంత్రమును ఉపయోగించిన వెబ్  పుటలును నిర్మించి సరిచేయుము. 
Comment[pt_BR]=Crie e edite textos e figuras em cartas, relatórios, documentos e páginas da Web por meio do Writer.
Comment[xh]=Dala uze uhlele isiqendu nezazobe zegrafu ezileteni, iingxelo, amaxwebhu namakhasi Othungelwano ngokusebenzisa i-Writer.
Comment[en_GB]=Create and edit text and graphics in letters, reports, documents and Web pages using Writer.
Comment[rw]=Kurema no guhindura umwandiko n'ibishushanyo mu mabaruwa, raporo, inyandiko na paji Rubuga ukoresheje Writer.
Comment[dz]=རྩོམ་འབྲི་པ་ལག་ལེན་འཐབ་ཐོག་ལས་ ཝེབ་པེཇི་དང་ ཡིག་ཆའི་རིགས་ སྙན་ཞུའི་རིགས་ ཡི་གུའི་རིགས་ཚུ་ནང་ལུ་ ཚིག་ཡིག་དང་ཚད་རིས་ཚུ་བཟོ་ནི་དང་ཞུན་དག་རྐྱབ་ནི།
Comment[tg]=Бо ёрии Writer матн ва тасвир сохтан, онҳоро ислоҳ кардан мумкин аст.
Comment[ca_valencia]=Creeu i editeu textos i gràfics en cartes, informes, documents i pàgines web amb el Writer.
Comment[de]=Erstellen und bearbeiten von Text und Grafiken in Briefen, Reports, Dokumenten und Web-Seiten - Writer macht's möglich.
Comment[pa_IN]=ਰਾਇਟਰ ਨਾਲ ਪੱਤਰਾਂ, ਰਿਪੋਰਟਾਂ, ਡੌਕੂਮੈਂਟਾਂ ਅਤੇ ਵੈੱਬ ਸਫ਼ਿਆਂ ਵਿੱਚ ਟੈਕਸਟ ਅਤੇ ਚਿੱਤਰ ਬਣਾਏ ਅਤੇ ਸੋਧੇ ਜਾ ਸਕਦੇ ਹਨ।
Comment[ast]=Crear y editar testos y gráficos de cartes, informes, documentos y páxines Web usando Writer.
Comment[tr]=Writer kullanarak mektuplardaki metin ve grafikleri, rapor, belge ve Web sayfaları oluşturabilir ve düzenleyebilirsiniz.
Comment[ro]=Creați și editați textele și grafica din documente, scrisori, rapoarte și pagini web folosind Writer.
Comment[nn]=Med Writer kan du laga og redigera tekst og bilete i brev, rapportar, dokument og nettsider.
Comment[ne]=लेखकको प्रयोगद्वारा चिठ्ठीहरू, प्रतिवेदनहरू, कागजातहरू र वेब पृष्ठहरूमा पाठ तथा ग्राफिक्स सिर्जना तथा सम्पादन गर्नुहोस् ।
Comment[en_ZA]=Create and edit text and graphics in letters, reports, documents and Web pages by using Writer.
Comment[as]=Writer ব্যৱহাৰ কৰি চিঠি, সংবাদ, দস্তাবেজ আৰু পৃষ্ঠাবোৰত থকা লিখনী আৰু গ্ৰাফিক্স সৃষ্টি আৰু সম্পাদনা কৰক।
Comment[sl]=S programom Writer ustvarjajte in urejajte besedilo in slike v pismih, poročilih, dokumentih in spletnih straneh.
Comment[nb]=Opprett og rediger tekst og bilder i brev, rapporter, dokumenter og nettsider ved å bruke Writer.
Comment[sk]=Vytvárajte a upravujte textové a grafické listy, správy, dokumenty a webové stránky s použitím Writer.
Comment[gu]=લખાણ દ્દારા પત્રો, અહેવાલો, દસ્તાવેજો અને વેબ પાનાઓમાં લખાણ અને ચિત્રો બનાવો અને સુઘારો.
Comment[ml]=റൈറ്റര് ഉപയോഗിച്ച്  കത്തുകളിലെയും റിപ്പോര്ട്ടുകളിലെയും ഡോക്കുമെന്റിലെയും വെബ് പേജിലെയും  ടെക്സ്റ്റും ഗ്രാഫിക്സും സൃഷ്ടിക്കുകയും എഡിറ്റു ചെയ്യുകയും ചെയ്യുക.
Comment[nl]=Met Writer kunt u tekst en afbeeldingen in brieven, rapporten, documenten en webpagina's maken en bewerken.
Comment[nr]=Enza nokuhlela itheksti neentjengiso eziseencwadini, emibikweni, emitlolweni nemakhasini weWebh ngokusebenzisa i-Writer.
Comment[ts]=Cinca ni ku lulamisa marito ni vudirowi eka mapapila, swiviko, tidokumente ni tipheji ta Web hi ku tirhisa Writer.
Comment[ug]=Writer ئىشلىتىپ خەت-چەك، دوكلات جەدۋىلى، پۈتۈك ۋە تور بەتتىكى تېكست ۋە گرافىكلارنى قۇرۇپ تەھرىرلىگىلى بولىدۇ.
Comment[fr]=Writer - Création et édition de textes et d'images pour courriers, rapports, documents et pages Web.
Comment[eo]=Krei kaj redakti tekston kaj grafikaĵojn en leteroj, raportoj, dokumentoj kaj TTT-paĝoj per Verkilo.
Comment[mn]=Writer ашиглан захиа, тайлан, баримт дахь бичвэр ба график үүсгэх болон засварлах.
Comment[ta]=கடிதங்கள், அறிக்கைகள், ஆவணங்கள், வலைப்பக்கங்கள் ஆகியவற்றின் உரை, படங்கள் இவற்றை உருவாக்கவும் தொகுக்கவும் ரைட்டரைப் பயன்படுத்துக.
Comment[eu]=Testua eta grafikoak sortu eta editatu gutunetan, txostenetan, dokumentuetan eta web orrietan Writer erabiliz.
Comment[be]=Стварайце і рэдагуйце тэкст і графіку ў лістах, справаздачах, дакументах і старонках Сеціва з дапамогаю Writer-а.
Comment[ru]=Создание и редактирование текста и рисунков в письмах, отчётах, документах или веб-страницах.
Comment[mr]=Writer चा वापरून पत्रं, अहवाल, दस्तऐवज व वेब पान अंतर्गत पाठ्य व चित्रलेख बनवा व संपादीत करा.
Comment[st]=Bopa le ho lokisa mongolo le ditshwantsho mangolong, ditlalehong, ditokomaneng le maqepheng a Wepe ka ho sebedisa Writer.
Comment[ss]=Yakha u-edithe umbhalo nemagrafiki etincwadzini, umbiko, wemadokhumenti nemapheji eWebhu ngekusebentisa Writer.
StartupNotify=true
Keywords=Text;Letter;Fax;Document;OpenDocument Text;Microsoft Word;Microsoft Works;Lotus WordPro;OpenOffice Writer;CV;odt;doc;docx;rtf;
InitialPreference=5
StartupWMClass=libreoffice-writer
X-KDE-Protocols=file,http,smb,ftp,webdav

Actions=NewDocument;
[Desktop Action NewDocument]
Name=New Document
Exec=libreoffice --writer
OnlyShowIn=Unity;`
```

Comment: I feel like you can't really run things in `.desktop` files. Point it to run with the original executable, which should be under `/lib/libreoffice/program`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However that directory does not exist in my `lib` folder.

I feel that I've searched my file-system high and low looking for the original program file, however the only thing turning up is the desktop link.

Comment: Open the desktop file with gedit and look at the path under the exec fieldm

Comment: Here is what I see `#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
#
# This file is part of the LibreOffice project.
#
# This Source Code Form is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public
# License, v. 2.0. If a copy of the MPL was not distributed with this
# file, You can obtain one at http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/.
#`

Comment: There's a character limit in comments. You either need to screenshot it or put it in your question.

Comment: I added to code

Comment: Hmm. Well, you might be able to make a script file and tell it to run that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Zotero's Libreoffice plugin for Firefox.

Go here [Zotero's plugins page](https://www.zotero.org/support/word_processor_plugin_installation)

scroll down until you see the Libreoffice plugin.  Firefox will give one of those warnings that it has not been verified by Mozilla or something to that effect.  Ignore and install.  You may need to re-star Firefox.

It works on my system. Hope it solves your issue.